# Why am I overwriting my firebase storageRef?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I have the following upload function where I'm trying to upload two images to firebase and combine their download urls in a collection.

How my second storageRef keeps overwriting the first one which results in only the compressed image being uploaded and me getting the link for the compressed image twice in my collection.

How do I fix this?

```
  const onUpload = async () => {
    if (file) {
      const options = {
        maxWidthOrHeight: 250,
      };
      const fullStorageRef = storage.ref();
      const fullFileRef = fullStorageRef.child(file.name);
      await fullFileRef.put(file);
      const fullUrl = await fullFileRef.getDownloadURL();
      const thumbnailStorageRef = storage.ref();
      const compressedFile = await imageCompression(file, options);
      const compressedFileRef = thumbnailStorageRef.child(compressedFile.name);
      await compressedFileRef.put(compressedFile);
      const thumbnailUrl = await compressedFileRef.getDownloadURL();
      db.collection("images").add({
        created: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        full: fullUrl,
        thumbnail: thumbnailUrl,
      });
      setFile(null);
    }
  };
```

Comment: One of the things I think would be possible to cause this is if you have your file.name the same as your compressedFile.name have you checked them?

Answer (score 0):

file.name and compressedFile.name were the same